# What is the result of fsck command if not run properly?

Tags: linux, fsck

If I ran this command

```
#fsck
```

without arguments or options. Will it delete everything?

Comment: Did you read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)?

Comment: No i didn't. I wanted to check file system. I searched and found this command and just ran it.

Comment: well, be happy that nothing have seemed to have happened, and from now on, read the man pages on whatever command you copied from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `fsck` will not cause any harm, unless you try to run it over mounted filesystem.

`fsck` over mounted filesystem will ask you if you want to proceed. And if you force it to proceed, then it is most likely to be very destructive. I have seen other people to use `fsck` this way and completely thrash Linux to the point that reinstall was necessary.

Comment: When I ran it, no prompt showed up. After that I go to the root directory and found that there is no file or directory.